# how to combine two numbers between an array of numbers with javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of numbers and would like to generate all possible combinations with 2 numbers as shown in the expected

```
const numbers = [1,2,3];
```

Expected:

```
const result = [
  [1,2],
  [1,3],
  [2,1],
  [2,3],
  [3,1],
  [3,2]
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permutations in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let num = [1,2,3];
let arr = [];

for(let i=0; i<num.length; i++){

  for(let j=0; j<num.length; j++){
    if(j === i) continue;
    arr.push([num[i], num[j]]);
  }

}

console.log(arr);
```